# defining custom loss function in pytorch and slower train time in GPU compare to CPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I define custom loss in the below, i change the all the tensor in the custom loss to be float32. but i dont know what to do. My gpu is GTX 1070.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqa1W.png)

I try to not use the for loop but because I define batch size I have problem about deleting the for loops.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please [don't share code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2257664), click on **Edit** and add the code in hte question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.